# How to increase the Page-speed score?

Tags: performance, magento2.2.3, optimization, pagespeed, minify

We have created a Website with **Magento 2.2.3**. The page-speed score of our website is too low. We have already have the followings with our website:

1. **Full Page Cache**
2. **Varnish Cache**
3. **Minify HTML and CSS**
4. **Image Optimizer**
5. **Memcache**

Apart from the above, we are running our site in the **Production mode**. Though we have all the above said points with our site, the **Page-speed score is too low**. Please see the attached screenshot which is taken from GTmetrix.

[image]

I have followed the suggestions provided by GTmetrix but still the score is low.

Please comment with your suggestion to get better Page-speed score.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already followed some steps regarding to page-speed score of website.

Please also try to follow bellow steps, This steps is also useful for improve page speed-up.

1. **Enable GZIP compression.**
2. **Use Lazy Loading for images.**
3. **Keep your Magento and 3rd party extensions up to date.**
4. **Use sprite image instead of separate images of small icons.**

I hope this will useful for you.:)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Can you please recommend me a best free Lazy Loading image extension for Magento 2?

Comment: Yes Sure, Please check this links for free lazy loading image extension

1) https://landofcoder.com/magento-2-lazy-load.html

2) https://www.weltpixel.com/magento-2-lazy-loading-enhanced.html